# How can a capacitor in a disposable camera shock you?

Tags: capacitor, voltage

The battery in a disposable camera is usually a single 1.5V AA battery.  It charges a large capacitor.  When the capacitor is fully charged, it will contain a voltage very close to 1.5V correct?

If one was to touch the charged capacitor, it will shock them.  Why is this?  Surely 1.5V can't do that kind of damage, right?

Comment: A TASER runs on a 9v battery, just sayin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Photoflash capacitors are charged to hundreds of volts using various methods (flyback transformer, etc). Don't assume that because the input is a AA battery that there are no greater potentials within the circuit.

The example below was taken from a Texas Instruments application note. This circuit is battery powered yet charges a capacitor to 300V.

[image: Photoflash Carger]

Comment: +1, also electric shockers often run on batteries yet they produce very high voltages using some clever electronics.

Comment: Ah, I never thought that there was a circuit that might be increasing the voltage.